# ScheduledExecutorService doesn't works during my junit test

Tags: java, spring, junit, scheduledexecutorservice

I am working on writing some junit test for my spring application. Below is my junit test that that calls `afterPropertiesSet` method of my `InitializeFramework` class that implements InitializingBean interface.

Below is the flow where my junit test calls `afterPropertiesSet` method and then that method will call `initializeModel` method within the same class, and then that method has a scheduler which will call `getBundlesInfo` method every few minutes. But somehow during my junit, `getBundlesInfo` method is not getting called at all.

```
@Test
public void testFramework() {


    try {
        InitializeFramework io = new InitializeFramework();
        io.afterPropertiesSet();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}


public class InitializeFramework implements InitializingBean {

private static long checkWithDBInterval = 1L;

private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        try {

        // other code here

        initializeModel();  
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    private void initializeModel() {

        final ScheduledFuture<?> taskHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            getBundlesInfo();
                        } catch(Exception ex) {
                            // log exception here
                        }
                    }
                }, 0, checkWithDBInterval, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }


    // this method is not getting called from my junit test 
    protected static void getBundlesInfo() {

    // some code here
    // have put the breakpoint here..

    }
}
```

Can anybody help me with this? What wrong I am doing here? but during my application run, this flow works perfectly fine and getBundlesInfo gets called... Only during junit it is not working..

Comment: I would guess the code relies on some other resources that are not running. You need to have a method the initializes all the needed resources. Use it together with the `@BeforeClass` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your unit test exits before the scheduler executes your Runnable.

Do you want to test that `afterPropertiesSet` calls `getBundlesInfo` or do you want to test the repeated invocation of `getBundlesInfo`?

How does your unit test assert that getBundlesInfo got called? Or are you not there yet?

If you just want to see that `getBundlesInfo` is called, you either could make a direct call to it and increase the `initialDelay` of your scheduler to `checkWithDBInterval`, or stub `getBundlesInfo` with Mockito and/or Powermock to for example use a CountDownLatch to synchronize on.

Well or just wait a couple of seconds after the call to `afterPropertiesSet` and then check if `getBundlesInfo` was called (which you can do with Mockito also btw).

In any case, you might want to add code which calls shutdown on the executor service after the test is finished

Since you use Spring:
Consider using the provided [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) framework to schedule the repeated call to `getBundlesInfo` and having afterPropertiesSet directly call getBundlesInfo initially.

Anyway, here is an example with stubbing and using a CountDownLatch for the waiting part.
I also had to make `getBundlesInfo` non-static, as i couldnt quickly remember/find how to stub a static method.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

public class StackOverflowTest
{

    public static class ClassWithScheduler
    {
        private static long checkWithDBInterval = 1L;
        private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool( 1 );

        public void entryPoint()
        {
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate( new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        thisHasToBeCalled();
                    }
                    catch( Exception ex )
                    {
                        // log exception here
                    }
                }
            }, 0, checkWithDBInterval, TimeUnit.MINUTES );

        }

        protected void thisHasToBeCalled()
        {
            System.out.println( "thisHasToBeCalled was called" );
        }
    }

    // since we are waiting on another thread either use a timed-wait (latch.await also
    // has a variant which accepts a timeout) or use the timeout attribute of the
    // @Test annotation
    @Test( timeout = 5000L )
    public void testCall() throws Exception
    {
        // create latch which this thread waits on and the scheduler thread
        // notifies on
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch( 1 );

        // create instance
        ClassWithScheduler instance = spy( new ClassWithScheduler() );

        // stub thisHasToBeCalled to notify on the latch
        doAnswer( new Answer<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void answer( InvocationOnMock invocation ) throws Throwable
            {
                // call the real method
                invocation.callRealMethod();

                // notify waiting thread
                latch.countDown();

                System.out.println( "stub" );

                return null;
            }
        } ).when( instance ).thisHasToBeCalled();

        // execute
        instance.entryPoint();

        // wait for thread to call the stubbed method
        latch.await();

        // assert that the method was called / 
        verify( instance ).thisHasToBeCalled();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will notice that if you change your `getBundlesInfo()` to something like

```
    protected static void getBundlesInfo() {
        System.out.println("ay");
    }
```

and the `TimeUnit` you are using to `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS`, that it will print as much as it can. For example, I got

```
ay
ay
ay
ay
```

This is because JUnit cleans up any threads running on the JVM before exiting. It kills/stops/interrupts them.

Comment: I see...Can you please elaborate little bit on this statement- `This is because JUnit cleans up any threads running on the JVM before exiting.`  So what I am supposed to do in my case to make this thing work?

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T Depending on what you want to happen, you could make your `@Test` sleep/wait for some notification from the threaded code. This is not particularly clean for a unit test.

Comment: In my case, I am trying to make a call to getBundlesInfo method by calling afterPropertiesSet method. I am not where should I sleep/wait in my @Test and also, how to have some sort of notification from the threaded code? Any thoughts?

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T You can use a callback interface (look that up), but the more I think about it the less I think you should use an `ExecutorService` in this way, ie. to initialize a bean.